# Why can't Maven find my SNAPSHOT artifact when I can download it manually just fine?

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-metadata

I have the world's simplest Maven/Jenkins/Nexus setup.

Maven runs via Jenkins dozens of times a day and deploys `SNAPSHOT`s to our Nexus repository just fine.

Every once in a blue moon, with seemingly no cause, running another Maven job that requires resolution of `SNAPSHOT`s will fail.  It fails in these rare cases with Maven telling me that it cannot any longer find the `SNAPSHOT`s that it uploaded in many cases several hours before.

If I point my web browser at the very repository location that Maven is using I can find them just fine.

Immediately before these errors, I always see (as I do in success cases) a bunch of `maven-metadata.xml` files being downloaded.  Presumably these files tell Maven something about how to take, e.g. `1.009-SNAPSHOT` and turn it into `1.009-somehugetimestamphere`.

(<s>I have never found any documentation of this file</s>, and it does not seem to mark any of the filenames contained therein as "latest" or anything similar.  In fact I cannot see how it is of any use at all, but clearly it must be.)

(I also see various references to `resolver-status.properties` in the debug output, which seems to be another undocumented file written to the local repository that tracks something having to do with resolution, but I confess I don't know what.)

My broad question is: how exactly *does* Maven go about downloading and resolving and checking `SNAPSHOT`s?  Assuming that the repository information is valid (after all, this job works 90% of the time and fails 10% of the time with no changes), what steps does Maven take with a given repository to find the proper `SNAPSHOT`?

**EDIT:** Found *some* documentation: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-repository-metadata/repository-metadata.html although it doesn't explain why none of the `maven-metadata.xml` files I find in my Nexus 2.0 installation have the `<latest/>` element in them.  Nor does it detail how these files are used.

My [posting on the users list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201208.mbox/%3CCAHNdxu%3DnbgAjiw1_wiqdnhdeQw7O8-69ki23pZNJsCcGZTLSvg%40mail.gmail.com%3E) brought a response that some of this might be a Nexus problem, in that it may or may not be generating these `maven-metadata.xml` files properly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a very similar problem the other day with a Nexus server proxying another repository. In my case, changing the Expiration Settings in Nexus fixed the problem. I reduced the "Artifact Max Age" and "Metadata Max Age" from 1 day to 1 minute.

Comment: Thank you; that is helpful, but was not the root issue.

Comment: Just curious, could you update the question with whatever you found as the root cause?